# Angular ng generate component creates folder outside src/app

Tags: angular

I am running this command `ng generate component` in a multi project workspace. However, the component gets created outside the `src\app` folder. How do i fix this such that the component gets created inside `src\app` folder?

```
my-angular-apps\projects\jokes> ng g c Jokes --skip-import --dry-run
CREATE projects/jokes/jokes/jokes.component.html (20 bytes)
CREATE projects/jokes/jokes/jokes.component.spec.ts (552 bytes)
CREATE projects/jokes/jokes/jokes.component.ts (198 bytes)
CREATE projects/jokes/jokes/jokes.component.css (0 bytes)
```

This is my desired output

```
my-angular-apps\projects\jokes> ng g c Jokes --skip-import --dry-run
CREATE projects/jokes/src/app/jokes/jokes.component.html (20 bytes)
CREATE projects/jokes/src/app/jokes/jokes.component.spec.ts (552 bytes)
CREATE projects/jokes/src/app/jokes/jokes.component.ts (198 bytes)
CREATE projects/jokes/src/app/jokes/jokes.component.css (0 bytes)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a command that gives me the desired results.

Run this from the workspace root directory.
Note:- the `--project` option is employed to mention which project this component will be part of. This will be helpful in a multi project repo.

```
❯ ng generate component jokes/JokesList --project jokes --skip-import
```

Or run this from the project root (this will be the projects/project-name directory)

```
❯ ng generate component src/app/jokes/JokesList  --skip-import
```

Note:-
The path seems to be specified via the component name argument itself
When run from the project root, I don't know why the src/app is not recognized as default location. instead, i specifically have to say `src/app/folder-of-component/ComponentName`

When run from the workspace root directory, the src/app is automatically recognized.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you are in main directory while running this command.
You can try to add the folder path also as

> ng generate component my-component --path src/app

Comment: hello! can you pls explain what main directory means? this is a multi project workspace. So are you referring to the workspace directory or the project directory?

Comment: Where the package.json is located